# Eumerate over two different tensorflow batchDatasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a VAE to convert an images of one type into images of another type. The problem I am having is when I call to train the model, telling it that I want the after image to be different.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

image_dir = r"BLAH\images\\"
images = [os.path.join(image_dir, image) for image in os.listdir(image_dir)]

mask_dir = r"BLAH\masks\\"
masks = [os.path.join(mask_dir, mask) for mask in os.listdir(mask_dir)]

image_size = 512

def preprocess(image):
    print(image)
    image = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (image_size, image_size))
    image = image / 255.0
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape = (image_size, image_size, 3))
    return image

batch_size = 20
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(images)))
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(preprocess)
training_dataset = training_dataset.batch(batch_size)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(masks)))
validation_dataset = training_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

.
.
.

```
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    print("Epoch", epoch)
    for step, training_batch in enumerate(training_dataset):
        print(training_dataset[0])
        print(step, training_batch)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            reconstructed = model(training_batch)
            y_true = tf.reshape(training_batch, shape = [-1])
            y_pred = tf.reshape(reconstructed, shape = [-1])
            mse_loss = reconstruction_loss(y_true, y_pred)
            mse_losses.append(mse_loss.numpy())
            kl = sum(model.losses)
            kl_losses.append(kl.numpy())
            train_loss = 0.01 * kl + mse_loss
            grads = tape.gradient(train_loss, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

In the line:
y_true = tf.reshape(training_batch, shape = [-1])
I want to be able to put a validation_batch but I don't know how to enumerate over two different _BatchDataset's